# Why reading/unpacking data from itertools.permutation changed its attribute/content?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to use the permutation feature from itertools, then I noticed. If I try to unpack/read the data from permutation, it changes some attribute info

```
from itertools import permutations

a = permutations('abc')


print(('a', 'b', 'c') in a)

for x in a:
    print(x)

print(('a', 'b', 'c') in a)

for x in a:
    print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
True

('a', 'c', 'b')
('b', 'a', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'a')
('c', 'a', 'b')
('c', 'b', 'a')

False
```

How come does this happen? I checked out the official page, and cannot find any clue.
My environment is pycharm with python 3.7.4

Comment: `permutations()`, like everything else from `itertools`, returns an *iterator*.  You consumed some elements from that iterator in your first `in` check, then consumed all of the rest in the first `for` loop.  At that point, the iterator is empty.

Comment: @jasonharper very clear explained, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others aready said, the problem is that `a` is not a list, but a generator; that is, a sequence that gets used up as you iterate over it -- hence you can only iterate over it once.

If you look carefully, you'll see that your first print loop only printed five of the six permutations; the first permutation disappeared when you checked it against `('a', 'b', 'c')` in your first `print` statement. The `for`-loop then prints out what's left, and the rest of your code is trying to drink from an empty cup.

To get the behavior you expect, make `a` into a list like this:

```
a = list(permutations('abc'))
```

And when you get a chance, read up on generators, iterators, and "comprehensions"; they're everywhere in Python (often hidden in plain sight), and they're great.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid from generator and convert the output to list since the comparison is vanishing because it used already. `itertools.permutation` is just an iterator which is shifting to next when you use one value in comparison.

CODE:

```
from itertools import permutations

a = list(permutations('abc'))


print(('a', 'b', 'c') in a)

for x in a:
    print(x)

print(('a', 'b', 'c') in a)

for x in a:
    print(x)
```

OUTPUT:

```
True
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'c', 'b')
('b', 'a', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'a')
('c', 'a', 'b')
('c', 'b', 'a')
True
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'c', 'b')
('b', 'a', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'a')
('c', 'a', 'b')
('c', 'b', 'a')
```